# Why I get this error message:'This API project was not found'while I'd created API key in console.developers.google.com

Tags: node.js, httprequest, google-maps-api-2, api-key

All of my code is here:

```
const request = require('request');
request({
  url:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?
key=*myKey*&address=1301%20lombard%20street%20philadelphia',
json: true
}, (error, response, body) => {
console.log(body);
});
```

and I receive this on command prompt:

> {
>
> > "error_message": "This API project was not found. This API project may >>have \n    been deleted.",
> > "results": [],
> > "status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
>
> }

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue as you, and figured it out:

```
const request = require('request')
const key = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
request ({
    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1301%20lombard%20street%20philadelphia%3F&?key=' + key,
    json: true
}, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(body, undefined, 2))
})
```

I think you're missing the `&` before `?key`.